# Strange Unicode in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, unicode, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been tracing an error with Paypal's IPN listener for a while where everything was just perfect for long time. After manually logging the queries to a TXT file, here is what I noticed:

```
INSERT INTO 'payments' VALUES (NULL, '41', '40', '', '-', 'completed', ...
```

While this looks just great for you too, it has a gimmick in that EMPTY VALUE after the '40' field value.. Its is **NOT EMPTY** as you might think or as it might appear from the first look.

Try it.. 
Copy that line of MySQL code and paste it into your notepad or even browser's address bad and you'll notice that it actually have 4 hidden characters  that look like squares as follows:

[image: The hidden UNICODE squares]

I think, those are the exact char's that are ruining my MySQL query.

Any explanation why Paypal is sending me those garbage chars will be appreciated. A solution to that would be even more appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow for example, DID detect those strange chars in my question and removed them automatically. So copying the string as I suggested will not work, but you still get the idea as I did post a screenshot.

Comment: `echo bin2hex($thatString)` – see what that string contains exactly.

Comment: I know excatly what it contains; Hebrew characters.

Comment: But in what encoding?

Comment: Well, using bin2hex " 5  4" converts to "1a1a1a1a1a1a1a2035201a1a1a1a2034".. any ideas?

Comment: `1A` is the "SUBSTITUTE" byte; sounds like encoding conversion has gone wrong at some point. Those are certainly not "Hebrew characters" anymore.

Comment: Thank you @deceze  but these lines are logged directly as received from Paypal IPN mechanism. Should I report it to them, or dig deeper where my server is doing this fuss?

Comment: If Paypal is indeed sending you garbage where you can guarantee it should not, yes, you should probably inquire with them.